# To take in count a statement or to ignore it PLSQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, inner-join

I'm new in SQL, so, a task was assigned to me to develop a stored procedure in oracle pl/sql, but now I'm sttopped due to the next question.

Is it possible to ignore or to take in count a INNER JOIN? I mean, i have to receive 2 parameters in the SP, they both could have values or just one of them, derived of that validation the inner join is necessary or not, so far I have the next code.

```
CREATE TABLE1 (
    FI_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    FC_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    FD_REGISTERED DATE,
    **FI_ID_TRAN_TYPE NUMBER**
);

CREATE TABLE2 (
    FI_ID_TRAN_TYPE INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FC_NAME VARCHAR2(30)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_SEL_INFO (
  PI_FI_ID_TRAN NUMBER NOT NULL,
  PI_DATE IN DATE,
  PO_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN PO_CUR_RESULTS FOR
    SELECT T1.FI_ID,
      T1.FC_NAME,
      T1.FD_REGISTERED
    FROM TABLE1 T1;
END;
```

Using the SP, From TABLE1 I need to get FI_ID, FC_NAME and FD_REGISTERED, but the conditions are the next, if PI_FI_ID_TRAN is not null and PI_DATE is null, I just need to retrieve data from TABLE1, but if both values (PI_FI_ID_TRAN and PI_DATE) are not null then I have to use a INNER JOIN to TABLE2 using FI_ID_TRAN_TYPE field. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, something like this might help:

```
open po_cur_results for
  select 
    t1.fi_id,
    t1.fc_name,
    t1.fd_registered
  from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.fi_id_tran_type = t2.fi_id_tran_type
  where (t1.fi_id         = pi_fi_id_tran or pi_fi_id_tran is null)
    and (t1.fd_registered = pi_date       or pi_date is null);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help. Best regards.